# What stylii will work with a 1st gen iPad mini?

Tags: ipad, bluetooth, stylus

I have a 1st gen iPad mini A1454 running iOS 9.3.6 and I would like to know what my options are when choosing a stylus. I know that Apple Pencil and compatible products will definitely not work, but that leaves both Bluetooth styluses and universal ones as options. Bluetooth styluses should work with select apps that support them (I have Brushes Redux installed). However, in an answer to a [similar question](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250921893) someone writes that there's also apparently a minimum Bluetooth version required to support those, which an older iPad may not have the hardware for. However, I am struggling to find any information about this and in general, searching for answers on this topic has been really exhausting.

Does my iPad support Bluetooth stylii and what stylus would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option that I have used and like is the [Bamboo Sketch](https://www.wacom.com/en-us/getting-started/bamboo-sketch) from Wacom. This item is compatible with your iPad Mini 1 Gen ([specs for reference](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/ipad/specs/apple-ipad-mini-original-a1454-4g-lte-att-specs.html)).

> #### [Bamboo Sketch Compatibility](https://support.wacom.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500006328762-Bamboo-Sketch-Compatibility)
>
> - 1 year ago -   Updated
>   Made for Apple iOS devices
>
> Make sure to pair Bamboo Sketch with a compatible app when using it with these devices.
>
> iPads
>
> - 12.9-inch iPad Pro
> - 9.7-inch iPad Pro
> - iPad Air 2
> - iPad Air
> - iPad mini
> - iPad mini 2
> - iPad mini 3
> - iPad mini 4
> - iPad (3rd generation)
> - iPad (4th generation)
> - iPad (5th generation)

[image]

Comment: That does look interesting, thanks. It seems however that Brushes Redux doesn't support this stylus?

Comment: I like the reviews for Bamboo Sketch and I might buy it (although it seems my only option is to buy used with shipping from a different part of the country), however if I am to insist on Brushes Redux as my app of choice, it seems that it only supports Apple Pencil and Pogo Connect

Comment: Yes, it is no longer for sale but I was able to get a "Like New" on eBay for a decent price. Even though it is not directly supported in Brushes Redux, the Bamboo Sketch can still act as a capacitive stylus.

Comment: Thank you, I bought the stylus and I am really happy with it!